# Getting uninitialized error when running my perl script

Tags: perl, variables

I am entering the first argument as "-d" and the second argument is a directory as long as it is a valid directory name.

Below is a snip of my code:

```perl
if ($ARGV[0] eq "-d" && -d $ARGV[1]){
        print "File Names       Size    Owner   Group\n";
        if (-d $ARGV[1]){
            my $newdir = ARGV[1];
            opendir(DIR, $newdir) or die $!;
        while (my  $file = readdir(DIR)){
                my $filename = "$file";
                my $size = -s $filename;
                my $gid = (stat("$file"))[5];
                my $group = getgrgid($gid);
                next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
                print "$file    $size   $gid    $group\n";
        }
        closedir(DIR);
    }
}
```

I am trying to return a list of all the file names, the file size, the file owner, and the group owner. When I execute the script it returns the file names, but i get errors for the size and owners. The specific error is

```
Use of uninitialized value $gid in getgrgid at ./tester.pl line 73.
Use of uninitialized value $size in concatenation (.) or string at ./tester.pl line 75.
Use of uninitialized value $gid in concatenation (.) or string at ./tester.pl line 75.
```

I am not sure why it is stating the `$gid` and `$size` variables are not initialized

Comment: It is a warning, not an error. Also, it's poorly worded; it means they are undefined (value is undef), which is also true before anything is assigned to them but in this case means that `-s` and `stat` returned undef. You need to check for errors.

Comment: it simply means that the variable is undefined (declared but does not contain any value), this is not an error, its a warning and you better stick to `use strict; use warnings;`, if you don't want to keep your script working on undefined variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninitialized can also mean initialized to `undef`.

`stat` and `-X` operators return `undef` and set `$!` on error. Let's add this error checking. At the same time, I'll also reduce the number of `stat` system calls from 2 + 2 per file to 1 per file.

```
if ($ARGV[0] eq "-d") {
    die("Usage\n") if @ARGV < 2;

    my $dir_qfn = $ARGV[1];
    opendir(my $dh, $dir_qfn)
        or die("Can't open dir \"$dir_qfn\": $!\n");

    my @rows;
    while (my $fn = readdir($dh)) {
        next if substr($fn, 0, 1) eq '.';

        my ($size, $gid, $group);
        if (my @stats = stat($fn)) {
            $size  = $stats[7];
            $gid   = $stats[5];
            $group = getgrgid($gid);
        } else {
            warn("Can't stat \"$fn\": $!\n");
            $size  = '???';
            $gid   = '???';
            $group = '???';
        }

        push @rows, [ $fn, $size, $gid, $group ];
    }

    # Print rows here.
    # By having all the data in an array,
    # you can figure out how wide to make the columns.
}
```

That's just a cleaned up version of your code. I haven't actually fixed the error yet. But since it has error checking now, we can see what the problem is. Running the program gives us `No such file or directory` for each and every file name! That's because you are looking for the file name in the current work directory instead of the directory to which is belongs.

To fix this, simple replace

```
if (my @stats = stat($fn)) {
...
    warn("Can't stat \"$fn\": $!\n");
```

with

```
 my $qfn = $dir_qfn . '/' . $fn;
 if (my @stats = stat($qfn)) {
...
    warn("Can't stat \"$qfn\": $!\n");
```

Comment: So when i try this I am getting "Bad symbol for dirhandle" at the line: while (my $fn = readdir($dir_qfn)) if I change $dir_qfn to $dh i get the warning for Can't stat... again it will print all of the file names but obviously not getting any of the stats

Comment: Yes, it should be `$dh`. Fixed. The rest stands. You need to pass the path to the file (`$qfn`) and not just its name (`$fn`).